# Proving a sequence by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove closed form for a sequence by induction. I have the sequence $\lbrace 0,2,6,14 \rbrace$. I found that the closed form for the sequence is $$\sum_{i=0}^n ( (2^{i + 1}) - 2).$$ I am trying to prove this by using induction. My attempt at a solution:

*Base cases*.
$$n = 0 \qquad \sum_{i=0}^0 (2^{0 + 1} - 2) = 0$$
$$n = 1 \qquad \sum_{i=0}^1 (2^{1 + 1} - 2) = 2$$

*Inductive Hypothesis*. Assume true:
$$\sum_{i=0}^k (2^{i+1} - 2) = 2^{k + 1} - 2$$

*Inductive step*.
$$\sum_0^{k+1} (2^{i + 1} - 2) = (2^{k + 2}) - 2 + \sum_0^k (2^{i + 1} - 2)$$

By the inductive hypothesis we can transform $\sum_0^k (2^{i + 1} - 2)$ into $2^{k + 1} - 2$. We obtain
$$((2^{k + 2}) - 2) + 2^{k + 1} - 2$$

That is as far as I got in my proof. I need some property or algebraic manipulation that can make that $2^{k + 1} - 2$ cancel so I can prove for $k + 1$. Any hints or ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you are trying to do. You have this sequence of four numbers and you are trying to find the closed form? If so, this is impossible, because there are infinitely many solutions. For example, you can interpolate the numbers with a polynomial. So I don't understand what you want to do with an induction...

Comment: Various issues:  (a) $2^{i+1}-2$ works to generate $0,2,6,14$ for $i=0,1,2,3$ but it is not the only possibility; (b) $\sum_{i=0}^n ( (2^{i + 1}) - 2)$ looks like an expression for the partial sum not the sequence; (c) it is not a closed form; (d) the closed form would not be $2^{k+1}-2$ though might be $2^{n+2}-2(n+2)$

Comment: (1) There is no *unique* closed form for any finite sequence (2) What do you want to prove? Do wou want to show that the sum you wrote down agrees with the elements of the sequence? If so, as the sequence is finite, it suffices to check the finitely many cases (of which there are four) (3) As you only know four (i.e. finitely many) elements of the sequence, the induction step does not make sense (as it would show equality for all natural numbers $n$) (4) In summary: Think again about what you really need and want to prove. Then try to write this down precisely. Only then start calculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written is not correct. Since for $n=2$ you have

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2} (2^{i+1}-2)=(2^{1}-2)+(2^{2}-2)+(2^{3}-2)=2+6=8\neq6.$$

The $n$-the term should be written as $a_{n}=2^{n+1}-2$ for $n=0,1,2,3$. You don't need induction to prove this since there's only $4$ terms in the sequence. Just check it is satisfied for each $n$.

Moreover you have $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+2=2(2^{n+1}-2)+2=2^{n+2}-4+2=2^{(n+1)+1}-2.$

(You can write this as the recurrence relation: $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+2$ and $a_{0}=0.$)